# Difference between esc_url() and esc_url_raw()

Tags: urls, escaping

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2239

I'm confused about when should either of them be used.

Assuming I have this URL: `http://site.com/?getsomejavascript=1`, which is dynamically generated javascript:

- if I include the script with `esc_url(add_query_arg('apples', 420))`, I get `http://site.com/?getsomejavascript=1&#038;apples=420` and it breaks because of those `#038;` references
- if I use `esc_url_raw(add_query_arg('apples', 420))` I get the correct URL: `http://site.com/?getsomejavascript=1&apples=420`

but in the documentation I find out that esc_url_raw should only be used to escape URLs inserted in the database...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Codex entry for Data Validation: URLs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs):

> `esc_url( $url, (array) $protocols =
>   null )` (since 2.8)
>
> Always use esc_url when sanitizing
>   URLs (in text nodes, attribute nodes
>   or anywhere else). Rejects URLs that
>   do not have one of the provided
>   whitelisted protocols (defaulting to
>   http, https, ftp, ftps, mailto, news,
>   irc, gopher, nntp, feed, and telnet),
>   eliminates invalid characters, and
>   removes dangerous characters.
>   Deprecated since 3.0: clean_url() This
>   function encodes characters as HTML
>   entities: use it when generating an
>   (X)HTML or XML document. Encodes
>   ampersands (&) and single quotes (')
>   as numeric entity references (&,
>   ').
>
> `esc_url_raw( $url, (array) $protocols
>   = null )` (since 2.8)
>
> For inserting an URL in the database.
>   This function does not encode
>   characters as HTML entities: use it
>   when storing a URL or in other cases
>   where you need the non-encoded URL.
>   This functionality can be replicated
>   in the old clean_url function by
>   setting $context to db.

So, the primary differences appear to be:

1. `esc_url()` encodes HTML entities,
   while `esc_url_raw()` does not
2. `esc_url()` is intended for
   *output*, while `esc_url_raw()` is intended for *database storage*

EDIT:

Since you are either hard-coding (or saving/storing separately) the actual URL from the query string, and then appending the query string via `[add_query_arg()][2]`, might it be better to escape your appended query string via `esc_js()`, rather than `esc_url()`?

For example:

```
add_query_arg( esc_js( 'apples' ), esc_js( '420' ), $myurl )
```

Comment: ok, but the `esc_url()` doesn't work properly when you have query arguments in a URL which you wanto to output

Comment: What about using `esc_js()` to escape just the data added via `add_query_arg()`? See edit in answer, above.

Comment: I didn't try it, but that doesn't make sense :) both esc_js('apples') or 'apples' will return `apples`. The problem is in add_query_arg when joins 'apples' with other arguments with `&`

Comment: Then, if the data are trusted (i.e. static), why escape at all?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it's safe to not escape it. I'm basically including script using something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>'/?javascriptcode=1"></script>`

Comment: Again: is `?javascriptcode=1` hard-coded/static? If so, then I think you might be attempting to escape the wrong entity. It is the `$_SERVER[]` data that are untrusted, *not* your hard-coded query string.

Comment: you are right, I think `esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` is enough

Answer (score 1):

**Let’s clear the confusion between `sanitize_url()`, `esc_url()`, and `esc_url_raw()` functions.**

**esc_url:**

```php
**esc_url( *string* $url, *string[]* $protocols = null, *string* $_context = 'display' ): string**
```

**sanitize_url:**

```php
**sanitize_url( string $url, string[] $protocols = null ): string**
```

implementation of sanitize_url() is:

```php
function sanitize_url( $url, $protocols = null ) {
    return esc_url( $url, $protocols, 'db' );
}
```

**esc_url_raw():**

```php
**esc_url_raw( string $url, string[] $protocols = null ): string**
```

implementation of esc_url_raw() is:

```php
function esc_url_raw( $url, $protocols = null ) {
    return sanitize_url( $url, $protocols );
}
```

**Conclusion:** `sanitize_url()` and `esc_url_raw()` both function implementation is same, and it uses the `esc_url()` function with **context** parameter **`‘db’`**.

**Use:**
`sanitize_url()` and `esc_url_raw()` is used to sanitize a URL for database or redirect usage.

Comment: @onetrickpony This should be the accepted answer