# esc_url, esc_url_raw or sanitize_url?

Tags: plugin-development, urls, security, sanitization, escaping

I know there's already [this post here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13572/difference-between-esc-url-and-esc-url-raw) but its answers still leave me in the dark about these three methods.

I'm a little confused by the selection of one of the methods mentioned in the title, if I want to generate a secure & dynamic URL which holds URL parameters. The use would be one of:

- HTTP redirect, executed in PHP
- page load, triggered via via js via `window.location = <escaped_link_if_clicked>`
- anchor tag link whose href value holds the escaped URL.

Now it seems that [esc_url_raw](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url_raw) under the hood executes [sanitize_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url_raw/#source) which in turn under the hood executes [esc_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_url/#source), in the end [applying the clean_url_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) via the `db` context.

Furthermore, `esc_url_raw` and `sanitize_url` share the exact same description in the docs, which is:

> Sanitizes a URL for database or redirect usage.

The [docs of esc_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) then state that ampersands are replaced if the context is `display`, which seems undesirable for URLs to me, as this would mean trouble for query parameters in your link. That's the reason why I currently use `esc_url_raw()` to generate safe URLs for all of the 3 cases mentioned above. If I however test:

`echo esc_url('https://example.org?my_query=is&so=cool')`

I get `https://example.org?my_query=is&so=cool`, so there's actually no encoding happening for the ampersand. So, to which ampersand do the docs actually refer to? Is my assumption correct that `esc_url_raw()` is the best way to go to avoid any issues with dynamically generated links with query parameters, for all of the three above-mentioned cases?

What also confused me is if you do:

```
var_dump(esc_url('https://example.com?test=hello&there=allgood',['https']));
var_dump(sanitize_url('https://example.com?test=hello&there=allgood',['https']));
var_dump(esc_url_raw('https://example.com?test=hello&there=allgood',['https']));
```

All of these give you:

`https://example.com?test=hello&there=allgood`

So what's the best way to go for my three above-mentioned scenarios?

The main reason why this question came up is that some snippets of well-known wordpress themes use `esc_url()` to generate links of `href` attribute values, and not `esc_url_raw()`, so I wondered about the reason why, and after digging I came to know about `sanitize_url()` too.

Comment: I just ran a quick test on my local WP installation, and `esc_url()` did in fact modify the `&` characters, changing them to `&#038;`. `&#038;` will appear in a browser as `&`; view the source code of the page, though, and you should see the difference.

Comment: ...I meant to add that `esc_url_raw()` passed the `&` through unaltered.

Comment: As for the `var_dump()` output, you should always check the raw/server-generated HTML source, because the on-screen output would actually show `&` even if it's indeed encoded in the HTML, because the browser will automatically decode it to a character which a human can understand. You can, however, use something like `echo '<pre>'; var_dump( esc_url( 'URL' ) ); echo '</pre>';` which can give you the raw output sent by the server to the client/browser.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @DevelJoe. But once again, `esc_url_raw()` is an alias for (i.e. it simply [calls](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L4499)) `sanitize_url()`, so, `esc_url_raw( 'URL' )` is equivalent to `sanitize_url( 'URL' )`. And despite `esc_url_raw()` still exists (i.e. not deprecated), it is recommended to call `sanitize_url()` directly, instead of the `esc_url_raw()` wrapper. See [53455](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/53455) (and [51597](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/51597)) in Trac for more details. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a more useful demonstration:

```php
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>>I'm printing a URL to the frontend</a>
```

```php
$url = sanitize_url( $_GET['user_inputted_data'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'that_url', $url );
```

`esc_url` is an escaping function, `sanitize_url` is a sanitising function.

- **Sanitising functions clean incoming data**, e.g. removing letters from phone numbers, stripping trailing space etc. This is the soap that cleans your data on the way into your site. Always sanitise user inputs and data from 3rd party/external sources such as forms and file imports.
- **Escaping functions escape data on *output*.** Why trust that the variable contains a URL when you can *force* it to be a URL and guarantee it. `esc_url` here makes everything into a URL, even if it is not. There's no sneaking in a script tag or other malicious HTML. Escaping functions are like cookie cutters, they enforce and guarantee their output will fit a particular shape or constraint. E.g. `esc_html` always returns plaintext, even if you pass it HTML it will escape the `<` and `>` so they're human readable plaintext.

You would never sanitise on output, just as you would never escape on input.

> Now it seems that esc_url_raw under the hood executes sanitize_url which in turn under the hood executes esc_url, in the end applying the clean_url_filter via the db context.

Indeed if you look at `esc_attr` and `esc_html` they both do the same thing, but that doesn't mean they're interchangeable. For one they have their own filters, so they might not be the same. It's also self-documenting. It's also a reminder that sometimes you should use other functions for attributes when you know more about their data type, e.g. `esc_url` for URLs, `intval` for integers, etc.

But what about `esc_url_raw`? Do not use this to escape output. It's stated quite clearly on the official WP developer docs sites entry for this function. **If you are trying to echo/print a URL in HTML, use `esc_url`.**

#### What About `esc_url_raw`?

In 99% of situations you will never need to use this, and on the frontend when outputting URLs it should never be used.

The primary reason you would want to use this is for database queries according to the official documentation:

> The esc_url_raw() function is similar to esc_url() (and actually uses it), but unlike esc_url() it does not replace entities for display. The resulting URL is safe to use in database queries, redirects and HTTP requests.
>
> This function is not safe to use for displaying the URL, use esc_url() instead.

Lets run through your examples:

> HTTP redirect, executed in PHP

Use `esc_url_raw` as the docs suggest.

> page load, triggered via via js via window.location = <escaped_link_if_clicked>

While you should `esc_url`, the important part is that this is inside javascript, so you actually have an additional step to do:

```php
window.location = <?php echo wp_json_encode( esc_url( $url ) ); ?>
```

Valid URLs can contain quotes, `wp_json_encode` can safely escape those for use inside javascript.

> anchor tag link whose href value holds the escaped URL.

**Always** `esc_url`, never `esc_url_raw`.

Comment: Cheers. Meaning I don't have to be afraid about issues related to query parameters when using `esc_url()` ? The part about the escaping of ampersands confuses me somewhat.

Comment: In the end, it thus all goes down to if you're rendering your URL which is supposed to be escaped within HTML or not. If yes, you use `esc_url()`, if not, you would use `esc_url_raw()`, correct?

Comment: don't use `esc_url_raw` unless you have a specific reason to need it, for every use of `esc_url_raw` will be a thousand uses of `esc_url`. On the frontend ***always*** use `esc_url`, and use it at the moment of output as late as you possibly can to avoid double escaping. `esc_url_raw` has very limited usage and is mainly used in crafting data that's intended for SQL. Most of the time you can ignore its existence. IMO you should place significantly less emphasis on `esc_url_raw`, its importance, and the concern it warrants.

Comment: and if you are not rendering output, then you shouldn't be escaping is the general rule 99.9999% of the time. Escaping functions are not validators or sanitisers, they're functions to use at the very last moment just as data is shipped to the browser, the final, last step. E.g. to use an escaping function before saving a value to the database would be incredibly bad practice.

Comment: likewise, if you're planning to use `esc_url_raw` everywhere that does not have an `echo` statement then that is also very bad practice, `esc_url_raw` has a specific well defined and very narrow use case. You should sanitise and validate your URLs with sanitising and validating functions such as `sanitise_url`

Comment: Yes got it. So I guess the only case where I'll really use `esc_url_raw` is for HTTP redirect in PHP then, as you said. Thanks!